# SQL Server Authentication vs Windows Authentication

Tags: sql-server

Good Afternoon,

I've been working on a problem where connecting to a remote default SQL instance (using the server's IP address) via Windows Authentication has been taking a lot longer than SQL Authentication.

Originally I thought that the problem was down to reverse DNS lookups but now I am not too sure. There was a record in the forward lookup zone for the server so connections using the server's name were quick. Once a record for the server was entered into the reverse lookup zone, the connections using the server's IP address were much faster.

So the issue appears to be fixed but I'm not so sure. Why wouldn't SQL authenticated connections have a similar problem? Do SQL authenticated connections not resolve against DNS?

Does anyone have any links to documentation on the internals of the two types of connections? I've been doing some research but have come up short.

Any links or advice would most appreciated.

Andrew

Comment: Check the responsiveness of your domain controller. I've seen issues like this when the primary had failed over to a much less capable backup DC. I don't think this is a DNS issue - if you connect by server name, the same lookup has to happen regardless of authentication method.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about network connections, not database administration.

Comment: Hi Max, I posted it in the DBA section as it was regarding connectivity of SQL Server. Happy for it to be moved if necessary.

Comment: I think the question is not merely about network connections. It is a Sql Server related problem, which happens specifically during Windows Authentication (this a sqlserver thing for sure imho?) It just so happens to be solved when a dns reverse lookup is added. This sort is, at least, hybrid - a cross between network and sql server. I happened to run into this problem myself and had confirm that adding a reverse dns record works on speeding up the Windows Authentication when connecting with IP address. And I too want to know why sql server wants a dns record - which seems irrelevant at first

Answer (score 3):

For Windows Authentication "SQL Server validates the account name and password using the Windows principal token in the operating system."

For SQL Server Authentication "logins are created in SQL Server that are not based on Windows user accounts. Both the user name and the password are created by using SQL Server and stored in SQL Server."

So SQL Server authenticated connections do not use DNS.

See this topic "Choose an Authentication Mode" in MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144284.aspx

EDIT: Even with SQL Server Authentication the initial connection to the SQL Server requires resolution of the SQL Server's name. It is, however, also possible to connect to the SQL Server using only the IP Address as you noted above.

See SQL Server name formats at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188642.aspx

Comment: I'm seeing conflicting behaviour. SQL authenticated connections for another server were failing (using the server name not IP address) but when a record was entered into the forward lookup zone, they then succeeded.

Comment: Resolving a server name is a different issue from login authentication, so I added an update.

Comment: Thank you, so the connection uses DNS to verify the server name before using the SQL credentials?